# Extract value of CPU usage from get-process command into variable, for further evaulation

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

This command gives me proper output:

`$Running = Get-process NODE | Select-Object CPU -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`

Output:

[Output screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRdAF.png)

I need to extract the number value from the returned object. Tried this via if, but .CPU returns nothing:

`if($Running.CPU -gt 1)  {Write-Output $Running}`

Comment: That's quite the gap in that property value. Could it have some white spaces for whatever reason? Does `$running.cpu` output the value on one line, or after one or two lines? Maybe you just need to call on `.Trim()`.

Comment: that indicates two things ... [1] your variable - `$Running` - is an array with more than one object in it. [2] some of those objects have blank or null `.Cpu` entries. i recommend you see what you are getting BEFORE your `Select-Object` call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what `NODE` is, but I do have 2 instances of `ttcalc` running on my computer so I did a test with it

```
Get-process ttcalc | Select-Object CPU -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | ForEach-Object {
    $Running = $_.CPU
    $Running
}
```

The output was:

```
2.484375
2.390625
```

Using GetType, it turns out that $Running is of type `Double`, so you should be able to do any calculation or test you want on it.

```
Get-process ttcalc | Select-Object CPU -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | ForEach-Object {
    $Running = $_.CPU
    if($Running -gt 2.42) {
        Write-Host "ttcalc output was $Running"
    }
}
```

Output:

```
ttcalc output was 2.484375
```

As you can see, it caught one ttcalc, but not the other.

Comment: Thanks, the command returned empty values for instances without CPU usage, and it didnt work without iterating trough all objects. So I used the ForEach-Object{} like you and it worked :)